# Form authentication not working when pasting restricted path in browser

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net site that uses the built-in form authentication. Site has an admin page that is used by an elevated account such as the administrator to update contents. The admin page is located one level down from root directory. I use log out button to raise the log out routine to terminate the session but if I paste the path to the admin file into the browser after I log out, I am able to access this restricted page. If I paste the path before I log in, I get the desired behavior, tThe login control looks like this.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <div style="float: left">
            <h2>
                Welcome
                <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />. <strong>You are logged in.</strong>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="actionbuttons">
            <Club:RolloverButton ID="Logoutbtn" runat="server" Text="Logout" OnClick="Logoutbtn_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
        </div>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <div class="actionbuttons">
            <Club:RolloverLink ID="Logintbtn" runat="server" Text="Login" NavigateURl="~/Login.aspx" CausesValidation="false" />
        </div>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

The code file is like this:

```
public partial class LoginBanner : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Logoutbtn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      Response.Clear();
      FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
      Session.Abandon();       
      Response.Redirect("./default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Login code from Default.aspx:

```
private bool IsAdmin;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _iAm = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"].ToString();
    Session["iAm"] = _iAm;

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (_iAm != string.Empty)
        {
            GetMemeberInfo(_iAm);
        }

    }
    IsAdmin = User.IsInRole("Administrators");
}

public void GetMemeberInfo(string userName)
{
    MemberIdByUserName getMyId = new MemberIdByUserName();
    Guid _myId = getMyId.GetMemberId(userName);
    Session["myId"] = _myId.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Post your login code on page_load event

Comment: Can you not use the built-in `LoginView` control instead of handling the logout routine yourself?

Comment: @JWLim, The form authentication is provided by the framework, why invent the wheel?

Comment: @Risho The `LoginStatus` control is also provided in asp.net by default. It provides a customizable `Login` link and `Logout` link for you depending on whether the user is logged in or not. If you use it, you save yourself the trouble of writing error-prone code to handle the logout routine, as you have done with `Logoutbtn_Click`.

Comment: @Risho Sorry, I meant the `LoginStatus` control in my first comment. This is how it looks like in code: `<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" />`

Answer (score 0):

On signOut event use:

```
Session["iAm"]=Null;
```

Comment: That is the same as `Session.Abandon();`, and it won't help.